how to reduce the space in gb4e example translations?
I'm writing a linguistics paper and I use gb4e package. For the sentence below, I don't know how to reduce the space between the two consecutive translations. Any other solutions than using \vspace{}.
Here is the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tipa}  

\usepackage{tikz} 

\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 

\usepackage{gb4e} 


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

    \ex

    \gll Ali [ mening ket-ken-lik-im-ni ] di-d-i.\\

    Ali [ \textsc{1sg.gen} leave-\textsc{rel-nmlz-poss.1sg-acc} ] say-\textsc{past-3sg}\\

    \textsc{Shifted}: \ding{55} `Ali_{i} said that he_{i} left.'


\textsc{Nonshifted}: \ding{51} `Ali said that I_{speaker} left.'

\end{exe}

\end{document}



Your code fails to compile: `Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \twosent was complete.

\par
l.1054
?Can you please fix it? If I fix that, I get an error because\ding` is undefined.

No idea if this is correct linguistic output, but here's a corrected and minimised version of your example which also addresses the spacing problem. As a general rule, if you don't want extra spacing, don't insert \\ followed by a paragraph break. (You shouldn't do that in most cases for independent reasons in most cases anyway.)
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{gb4e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
  
  \ex
  
  \gll Ali [ mening ket-ken-lik-im-ni ] di-d-i.\\  
  Ali [ \textsc{1sg.gen} leave-\textsc{rel-nmlz-poss.1sg-acc} ] say-\textsc{past-3sg}\\  
  \textsc{Shifted}: \ding{55} `Ali_{i} said that he_{i} left.' \\
  \textsc{Nonshifted}: \ding{51} `Ali said that I_{speaker} left.'
  
\end{exe}

\end{document}

Result with XeTeX:

